# How to retrieves plans of product in stripe?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

My stripe account has a [Product](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products) with [plans](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans) and I created a new product with two plans.
I m using Laravel cashier and I want to retrieve selected product's plans.

```
    $stripe = new StripeClient(config('services.stripe.secret'));
    $product = $stripe->products->retrieve(config('services.stripe.product'),[]);
    //$plans = $product->plans();//something like that
```

But I m unable to find a way to achieve this. the following method retrieves all plans from all products.

```
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(\config('services.stripe.secret'));
        $plans = $stripe->plans->all();
```

Can you please help me to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer of my Question.Just pass the product id in array like this,

```
 $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(\config('services.stripe.secret'));
 $plans = $stripe->plans->all(['product'=>config('services.stripe.product') ]);
```